# Transit visa travelling from Canada to India via Germany

Tags: visas, germany, transit, canada, indian-citizens

I have single entry tourist visa for Canada. My visa is valid till 20th Dec 2013 but I am travelling to Mumbai from Toronto on oct. end via Munich (Germany). I am an Indian passport holder. Do I need transit visa for germany? I will fly with Air Canada.

Answer (score 7):

**No**, you do not need a visa for going from Canada to India via Munich airport (or vice versa), as long as you stay in the transit area and have a connection in less than 12 hours.  [Lufthansa](http://www.lufthansa.com/online/portal/lh/in/local?nodeid=3116855&l=en), emphasis mine:

> 1. Indian nationals can Transit without Visa via FRA or MUC if holding a valid visa for the destination and a valid Visa for any of the
>      following countries:
>
> Bulgaria, **Canada**, Cyprus, Ireland, Japan, Liechtenstein, Romania, UK
>   and USA (the approval notice I-797 is not valid document for visa free
>   airport transit).

The site of the [German Consulate in Kolkata](http://www.india.diplo.de/contentblob/3174898/Daten/3387373/download_datei_transit_visa.pdf) confirms this as well.

Comment: What happens if your connection is more than 12 hours but you do not leave the transit area of Munich airport?